# Thinking Sphinx unknown identifier groupby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to use Thinking Sphinx search with group_by option according to documentation http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#grouping :

```
Point.search('point', group_by: :tour_id)
```

But this code generates incorrect Sphinx Query

```
SELECT *, groupby() as sphinx_internal_group, count(*) as sphinx_internal_count 
FROM `point_core`, `point_delta` 
WHERE MATCH('point') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `tour_id` LIMIT 0, 20
```

which raises error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::ParseError: index point_core,point_delta: 
parse error: unknown identifier 'groupby' (not an attribute, not a function) - 
SELECT *, groupby() as sphinx_internal_group, count(*) as sphinx_internal_count 
FROM `point_core`, `point_delta` WHERE MATCH('point') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `tour_id` LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META
```

I am using thinking-sphinx-3.1.1.

What is the correct way of group_by option usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Sphinx 2.0.x - Thinking Sphinx v3.1.x expects Sphinx 2.1.x by default. But you can [configure it](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/releases/v3.1.0) to behave in ways that Sphinx 2.0.x expects.

Comment: Yes. Old Sphinx was the root of evil. My installed Sphinx version was Sphinx 2.0.4 and currently I have upgraded it to 2.1.9. So, now it's work perfect. Thank you pat.