# Recent version of sphinxsearch on Debian 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, apt

I am using sphinxsearch in conjunction with Thinking Sphinx in my Rails app and now I ran into this problem: [Thinking Sphinx unknown identifier groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397577/thinking-sphinx-unknown-identifier-groupby)

Now locally I get the current version of sphinx by installing it through homebrew:

```
brew install sphinx
```

Now the version, which was installed is 2.2.4:

```
brew info sphinx

# sphinx: stable 2.2.5, HEAD
# http://www.sphinxsearch.com
# /usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/2.2.4 (15 files, 17M) *
```

On my production server I seem to have an outdated version of sphinxsearch which seems to be the cause of my problem:

```
apt-get update
apt-cache show sphinxsearch

# Package: sphinxsearch
# Version: 2.0.4-1.1
# Installed-Size: 9909
# Maintainer: Radu Spineanu <radu@debian.org>
# Architecture: amd64
# Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.5), libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1), libpq5, libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libstemmer0d (>= 0+svn527), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), adduser
```

Debian [says](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=sphinxsearch):

> #### Package sphinxsearch
>
> squeeze (oldstable) (misc): Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
>
> - 0.9.9-6: amd64 armel i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc s390 sparc
>
> wheezy (stable) (misc): Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
>
> - 2.0.4-1.1: amd64 armel armhf i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc s390 s390x sparc
>
> sid (unstable) (misc): Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
>
> - 2.0.4-1.1+b1 [debports]: sparc64
> - 2.0.4-1.1 [debports]: alpha amd64 armel armhf i386 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc powerpcspe ppc64 s390x sh4 sparc
> - 0.9.9-6 [debports]: hppa

So it seems that I can only install 2.0.x of sphinxsearch through apt. Why is this and how can I update without having to compile the package from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ubuntu packages here:
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/

just download and install via dpkg directly

Comment: I would prefer the package manager instead. For some reason there are 14 releases (2.5 years of development) missing in this special case. I believe sphinx is quite popular, so I am wondering why the official debian package was never updated

Comment: dpkg is a package manager! apt-get just provides a nicer interface. I guess whoever was maintaining the sphinxsearch package, lost interest and hasnt kept it updated. https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=radu%40debian.org

Answer (score 0):

You can add **latest stable** build releases for **2.2.*** of sphinx search to your system.

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:builds/sphinxsearch-rel22
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

more info about repository: https://launchpad.net/~builds/+archive/ubuntu/sphinxsearch-rel22/

PS: Dont forget to `sudo` all commands.